# Build error for cordova Visual Studio 2015 update 2

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

**Error Message**
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

I checked environment variables, it does have ANDROID_HOME and the same has been mentioned in Path variable value.

I am not sure why still I am getting this error. Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Run the dependency checker and see what it says. Try following http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/  to ensure required android sdk staff are installed.

Comment: I ran it but that did not work. Anyway, I was able to fix this by updating Android SDK (It was install and working, but I guess, Visual Studio needs few more updates )

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by updating Android SDK (It was install and working, but I guess, Visual Studio needs few more updates).

After updating, please check followings in Tools ---> Options:
1. Android SDK path is correct in Xamarin tools.
2. Cross platforms 
3. Cordova tools, environment variable section.

**PS**: I don't understand why Visual Studio is using these three separate options, and complexly ignores the Environment variable set at system level.